# Abbreviated definition of a webdriver html element

Tags: c#, webdriver, pageobjects

In webdriver, with c#, you can define a html element using this:

```
//Textfields        
public static IWebElement userFieldElement 
{
   get {return Configuration.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@name='USER']"));}
}
```

Is it there an abbreviated way of defining the same? I have tried:

```
public static IWebElement passwordFiedfElement = Configuration.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@name='USER']"));
```

But it is invalid because *webdriver* tries to find all the elements defined in this way if the class that contains them is called for any reason. The first method works, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible way is probably to use the [FindsBy](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_FindsByAttribute.htm) class

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//input[@name='USER']")]
public IWebElement userFieldElement { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am going for PageFactory.